# I keep getting "Extraneous input ')' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'" error in my code? Can anyone help me?

Tags: pine-script

In this piece of code, I keep getting the same issue but I don't understand what the problem is.

This is a strategy, not a study. I am coding this in Pinescript v5. Is my syntax wrong?

```
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, if hist > 0 and nz(hist[1]) <= 0)
strategy.close("Long", if hist < 0 and nz(hist[1]) >= 0)

strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, if hist < 0 and nz(hist[1]) >= 0)
strategy.close("Short", if hist > 0 and nz(hist[1]) <= 0)
```

This error appears after the 0 in the firs statement, and I guess will show in the other 0 for the following one if I fix the first one.

I have tried formulating the statements in different ways but I keep getting the same error..

Answer (score 0):

You should read the function signatures.

The third argument of the `strategy.entry()` is `qty` and the second argument of  `strategy.close()` is `comment`.

You are passing an if statement to those arguemnts which does not make any sense.

> strategy.entry(id, direction, **qty**, limit, stop, oca_name,
> oca_type, comment, alert_message) → void
> strategy.close(id, **comment**, qty, qty_percent, alert_message,
> immediately) → void

Call those functions inside your if conditions.

```
if (hist > 0 and nz(hist[1]) <= 0)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (hist < 0 and nz(hist[1]) >= 0)
    strategy.close("Long")

if (hist < 0 and nz(hist[1]) >= 0)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

if (hist > 0 and nz(hist[1]) <= 0)
    strategy.close("Short")
```